# Position fixed does not work when the virtual keyboard is shown in iOS

Tags: ios, css, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, virtual-keyboard

I'm developing an app using Worklight 6.2 where the layout has a fixed field of research in the header, when this field receives focus, the virtual keyboard of the operating system is presented.

Running this app on iOS (iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 the layout is larger than the screen) when the layout is not the beginning (was rolled down), the div and input that were fixed at the top (position: fixed) lose this configuration and are similar to absolute layout. Another problem is that the header (div and input), automatically cut some pixels, going to the center of the screen and was hidden divs that appear scrolling the page.

Below the prints of some situations and the source code with the problem.

Without showing the virtual keyboard (correct layout)
[image]

When show a virtual keyboard with layout rolled down
[image]

When does scroll the page with the virtual keyboard showing (Lose the configuration layout: fixed and apparently assumes the configuration layout: absolute)
[image]

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

        <style type="text/css">
            a,abbr,address,article,aside,audio,b,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,dialog,div,dl,dt,em,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,mark,menu,nav,object,ol,p,pre,q,samp,section,small,span,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,ul,var,video
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: 'MuseoSans-100';
            }

            /* Worklight container div */
            body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .div-header {
                height: 200px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #0094D9;
                position: fixed;
            }

            .input-header {
                margin-top: 100px;
                height: 40px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .div-body {
                height: 500px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .div-body-1{
                background-color: #ffff9f;
            }

            .div-body-2{
                background-color: #1b8127;
            }

            .div-body-3{
                background-color: #fb7d00;
            }
        </style>

        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>           
    </head>
    <body style="display: none;">
        <!--application UI goes here-->
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="div-header">
                <label class="span-header">Hello Worklight</label>
                <input maxlength="50" id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="BarCode" class="input-header">
            </div>
            <div id="div1" class="div-body div-body-1">
                Div 1
            </div>

            <div id="div2" class="div-body div-body-2">
                Div 2
            </div>

            <div id="div3" class="div-body div-body-3">
                Div 3
            </div>
        </div>



        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, I have noticed this in the iOS Simulator in the past, but not in a device. Are you testing this in a device?

Comment: Yes, this image is screenshoot of iPhone 5, the same problem happen in the iPhone 4.

Comment: Had you solved this issue . I am facing same issue .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue of screen distortion due to virtual keyboard can be resolved by adding `$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},'fast');` either on the screen-size change event or in case if the keyboard hides on touching any element then on `onclick event`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, adding this plugin to the project fixed it!

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard

After adding it, set `Keyboard.automaticScrollToTopOnHiding = true;`

and it will do the trick